# How to containerize a builder class in Aura.Di?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, auraphp

Without a DI container, you would normally do something like this:

```
$foo = (new FooBuilder)
->setA('a')
->setB('b')
->build();

// where $foo becomes an instance of Foo class
```

How do you register/containerize something like that in [Aura.Di](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Di)?

Answer (score 2):

Found it. For those who care, it's [lazyGetCall()](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Di/blob/4.x/docs/lazy.md)

E.g., If you have something like this:

```
$foo = (new FooBuilder)
->setA('a')
->setB('b')
->build();
```

You can containerize it like this:

```
$builder = new \Aura\Di\ContainerBuilder;
$di = $builder->newInstance();
$di>setters['FooBuilder']['setA'] = 'a';
$di>setters['FooBuilder']['setB'] = 'b';
$di->set('FooBuilder', $di->lazyNew('FooBuilder'));
$di->set('Foo', $di->lazyGetCall('FooBuilder', 'build'));
```

You can then call it elsewhere like this: `$fooInstance = $di->get('Foo');`